# Ruby on Rails: Replacing the "LIKE" part of the SQL query with Ruby code

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my application I have a "LIKE" SQL query that is something like...

```
Item.where("name LIKE ?", "%"+params[:q]+"%").all
```

But I want to hit the db only 1x (at application start-up), since the number of Items is huge, and load this generic part...

```
Item.all
```

...into memory (a global variable), so I can later reuse its content throughout the app, in different cases, and refined with some case-specific Ruby code (see the "LIKE" part).

What's the speediest way to do such "filtering" with Ruby?

Comment: Are you prematurely optimizing? Is your application really too slow? I suppose that the fastest (and easiest) way of applying the filters in Ruby, is to let the database handle it..! Database are build to do such jobs, Ruby is not.

Comment: *"number of Items is huge"*. Define "huge".

Comment: @Veger - I believe you're right, I was probably trying too hard to avoid hitting the database...

Comment: @ypercube - Although the entries contain lots of data each, "huge" was actually 5k entries.

So yes, I was prematurely optimizing and underestimating the power of databases.

Thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 0):

Could you use [Low level caching](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/caching-strategies#low-level-caching) for this?

Comment: It's true that low level caching is probably better than using a global variable (for the caching part of my question). But my specific case is an autocomplete dropdown menu which will of course generate a big number of different queries coming in very rapidly (i.e. everytime the user adds another character to the query term). Since there's a huge number of different LIKE queries that are possible, low level caching won't reasonably solve the "LIKE" part of my question...